How to run Keycloak behind Traefik in K3s?
my problem is simple, i did small website in dev mode in react.js and keycloak as auth service. Everyting worked as expected, but after deploying to "production" and getting everything in K3s, things wasnt going smooth as expected. Down here you can see my K3s yml files for Keycloak and bit of my React.js code ...
keycloak-deployment.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      tolerations:
        - key: "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready"
          operator: "Exists"
          effect: "NoExecute"
          tolerationSeconds: 15
        - key: "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable"
          operator: "Exists"
          effect: "NoExecute"
          tolerationSeconds: 15
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: bitnami/keycloak:25.0.2
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: KEYCLOAK_CREATE_ADMIN_USER
              value: "true"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USER
              value: "user"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              value: "password"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_VENDOR
              value: "postgresql"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_HOST
              value: "x.x.x.x"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PORT
              value: "5432"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_NAME
              value: "db_name"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER
              value: "bn_user"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSWORD
              value: "db_password*"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_SCHEMA
              value: "x"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT
              value: "8080"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT
              value: "8443"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_BIND_ADDRESS
              value: "0.0.0.0"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ENABLE_HTTPS
              value: "false"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME
              value: "sso.example.com"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_PRODUCTION
              value: "true"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_PROXY_HEADERS
              value: "xforwarded"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_EXTRA_ARGS
              value: "--http-enabled true"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: keycloak-themes
              mountPath: /opt/bitnami/keycloak/themes

      volumes:
        - name: keycloak-themes
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: keycloak-pvc

keycloak-svc.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak-svc
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP

keycloak-ingress.yml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: keycloak-ingress
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`sso.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/`)
      services:
        - name: keycloak-svc
          port: 8080
      middlewares:
        - name: keycloak-forwarded-headers
  tls:
    secretName: keycloak-tls-secret
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: keycloak-forwarded-headers
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  headers:
    customRequestHeaders:
      X-Forwarded-Proto: "https"
      X-Forwarded-Host: "sso.example.com"

React.js > app.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { getKeycloak } from './services/keycloak.js';
import ProtectedRoutes from "./services/ProtectedRoutes";

import './default.css';

const keycloak = getKeycloak();


function App() {

  const [userData, setUserData] = useState("");
  const [ssoFetched, setSsoFetched] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    console.log("Keycloak check-sso");

    keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'check-sso' })
      .then(authenticated => {
        if (authenticated) {
          getUserInfo();
        } else setSsoFetched(true);
        console.log("Keycloak authenticated:", authenticated);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Authentication error:', error);
      });

  }, []);

  const getUserInfo = () => {
    keycloak.loadUserInfo()
      .then(userInfo => {
        setUserData(userInfo);
        setSsoFetched(true);
        console.log(userInfo);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Failed to load user info:', error);
      });
  };


  return (...);
};

export default App;

Here in app.js i run keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'check-sso' }) to test if user is auth-ed and log him in if he is. In testing it worked perfectly, but after deploy it cant really check if user is still auth-ed seassion still "live", i tryed set some headers in treafik that i dont even know what they do.
keycloak.logout() and keycloak.login() works, even keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }) works, but not check-sso. for now that only thing i find you making problems. Do someone had same problem or do im missing something in docs ? Thanks to all.
I did try all configurations that i find online, but nothing works from time after deployment.
